# Files downloaded with ubuntu cannot be accesed with win 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, 13.04

I have a dualboot system with Ubuntu and Win 7. After updating ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 I encountered some problems:
When I download files with ubuntu to a shared ntfs partition, I cannot open them in windows 7. I can see the properties such as size and creation date, but when trying to open it, there is an error dialog: name of directory is not valid.
Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a encoding problem in the path name, try to remove any special characters in the path.